# Can I GROUP BY Year within a subquery of an SQL statement?

Tags: sql

I am trying to generate a dataset which will display `Year`, `SUM(Income)`, and `SUM(Expense)` grouped by `DATEPART(YYYY, TransactionDate)` from a single table (`AccountTransactions`).

However, for the returned `Income` column, I only want to include income that has a `Category = 'Income-Paycheck'`. I don't want any other income source tallied in the total. `SUM(Expense)` should be all expenditures from the `AccountTransactions` table.

My `AccountTransactions` table structure is:

```
AccountTransactionID    int 
TransactionDate         date        
Description             varchar(MAX)    
Expense                 float   
Income                  float   
AccountID               int 
Note                    varchar(MAX)    
Category                varchar(50)
```

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YYYY, TransactionDate) AS Year, 
    (SELECT SUM(Income) AS Income
     FROM AccountTransactions 
     WHERE  Category = 'Income - Paycheck') AS TotalIn, 
    SUM(Expense) AS TotalOut
FROM
    AccountTransactions 
WHERE 
    AccountId = 91
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YYYY, TransactionDate)
ORDER BY 
    Year Desc
```

The result is:

```
Year    TotalIn      TotalOut
------------------------------------
2023    358457.24     90587.7800000001
2022    358457.24    151930.6
2021    358457.24    197909.46
2020    358457.24     51612.19
```

I can see that `TotalIn` has tallied all income `WHERE Category = 'Income - Paycheck'` in the table and not grouped by year because I haven't told it to.

Is there a way to `GROUP BY Year` within the `Income` column?

I appreciate any help or guidance. Don't go too hard on me, this is my first post. :)

Comment: Instead of the scalar subquery, try `SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 'Income - Paycheck' THEN Income ELSE 0 END) AS TotalIn`

Comment: Tip - using imprecise floating-point for monetary data is a bad choice of data type, you should use `decimal/numeric`

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the tip! Clearly I'm a beginner and I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thanks to [Atmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20143744/atmo) for providing the answer to my question in the comments.  Instead of using a scalar subquery, I utilized a Case statement to return the result I was looking for.

My final SQL statement is:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YYYY, TransactionDate) AS Year, 
     SUM(
          CASE WHEN Category = 'Income - Paycheck' THEN Income ELSE 0 END
        ) AS TotalIn,
     SUM(Expense) AS TotalOut
FROM AccountTransactions 
WHERE AccountId = 91 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YYYY, TransactionDate) 
ORDER BY Year Desc
```

This gave me the desired result of:

```
Year    TotalIn     TotalOut
2023    75548.62    90587.7800000001
2022    120308.65   151930.6
2021    109821.9    197909.46
2020    52778.07    51612.19
```

Comment: And that's called _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: @jarlh Thankyou for pointing that out.  I'm going to read up on that now.